# Why can't I import from a directory?

Tags: python

My directory structure looks like:

[image]

In my `main.py`, I have:

```
from lib.dataset.cifar import load_cifar_10
```

And my `lib/data/cifar.py` has:

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.datasets import cifar10


def load_cifar_10():
    num_classes = 10

    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
    x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
    x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
    x_train /= 255
    x_test /= 255

    # Convert class vectors to binary class matrices.
    y_train = to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
    y_test = to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

    ret_val = {
        "x_train": x_train,
        "x_test": x_test,
        "y_train": y_train,
        "y_test": y_test,
        "num_classes": num_classes
    }

    return ret_val
```

But the error I get is:

```
    dataset = cifar.load_cifar_10()
NameError: name 'cifar' is not defined
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: `from lib.dataset.cifar import load_cifar_10` - that only imports the one function, under the name `load_cifar_10`. The name of the whole module, `cifar`, is not imported. But with this import, you can just access `load_cifar_10` directly.

Comment: Please post as an answer so I can accept

Comment: thanks, I will. I don't like to post things like that as an answer initially, in case I've missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `import` statement you used:

```
from lib.dataset.cifar import load_cifar_10
```

only imports the one function, under the name `load_cifar_10`. The name of the whole module, `cifar`, is not imported.

But with this import, you can just access `load_cifar_10` directly - so there is no need to use the "dot notation".